# How to think about absorption and emission rates and intensity for stimulated emission?

Tags: spectroscopy, absorption, emission

I learned Fermi's Golden Rule applied to absorption and stimulated emission and encountered the following question:

Since absorption and emission rates are the same for stimulated emission, why can't we say that the incident beam is not attenuated by the sample?

Comment: Hence the need for a population inversion

Comment: @JonCuster I understand population inversion means there are more molecules at the excited than at the ground state. Can you please elaborate on how this idea is connected to the question?

Comment: @EdV I know that stimulated emission occurs when the excitation frequency matches the energy gap frequency. I don't see exactly how that can be useful for this question though.

Comment: You also have spontaneous emission, at least. So if absorption and stimulated rates were exactly equal, and there was no other de-excitation pathway, the medium would be transparent, i.e., have no net absorbance at the relevant wavelength. So you cannot get there with a passive medium by blasting it with light. With an active medium, like the Xe flashlamp-pumped ruby rod, you get population inversion, so incident light at 694.3 nm results in even more intense 694.3 nm light (from the stimulated emission, i.e., laser action) being emitted.

Comment: @EdV Is it correct to understand that, in the case that the ground and excited populations are the same, the beam is attenuated (incident and exiting intensities differ) because of other relaxation pathways such as fluorescence and non-radiative relaxation?

Comment: Ignoring degeneracies, you are not going to get them the same, unless some pumping mechanism is involved. If you simply illuminate a solution of a fluorescent substance, e.g., rhodamine 6G laser dye, some of the incident light is absorbed, so the exit intensity is lower than the incident intensity. And there is fluorescence and heat produced.

Comment: Doesn't the absorption and stimulated emission rates being equal imply that the ground and excited states populations are equal, since the rate is proportional to the population? Please correct me if I misunderstood: what I got from your previous comment is that, for a passive medium like a solution of molecules, if the absorption and emission rates were the same, the exit beam would always have lower intensity than the incoming beam because of the energy loss in non-radiative relaxation.

Comment: Both the rates (abs & stim. emission) are proportional to the light intensity and *difference* in population between the states which is why we get attenuation in passing light through a solution as upper level popl'n is so small. In a laser the upper population has to be greater than lower one is, and so we can get gain if a photon of correct wavelength passes through. To get a laser three or four levels are necessary as 2 levels cannot lase; transition up is always equal to transition down when pumped hard enough.

Comment: In my opinion you are over thinking at this. If you are stable at a situation in which the two rates equal, then in principle and in ideal condition a photon matching the levels should stimulate emission. So the beam isn't attenuated but enriched. If you want lasing you need inversion, so some kind of pumping.

Comment: My final comment: have a look at [Einstein coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_coefficients).